# Is there any way to control how fast Wild Gunman fires with Duck Hunt's Down B?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Duck Hunt has a Down B that summons a random Wild Gunman, each of which seem to have their own damage percent and fire rate.

Is there any way to make the gunman fire early, or to control which Wild Gunman Duck Hunt summons?

Is there any pattern to which gunman appears when the Down B move is used, or is it completely random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the individual gunmen has their own independent damage and firing speed. It is not possible to alter when they shoot, or control which one appears.

The specific gunman that appears is random, but with limitations - all five must appear before one can appear twice. Or in other words, they're like a deck of cards - draw one of the five without replacement every time you use the move, and shuffle them again after the fifth time.